# How to remove header underline from psql output in aligned mode

Tags: psql, postgresql-9.1

I need to remove the header underline in psql from my query output. I need column names only, but don't need the underline part.

Current output:

```
Col1 col2
----------
Ab.   Cd
Ef.   Gh
```

But I need

```
Col1 col2
Ab.  Cd
Ef.  Gh
```

I need aligned mode only answer.

I tried `\qecho` to print column names, but the format is not coming properly.

I removed `-t`, and it's printing, but the underline is there.

Comment: I don''t think that is possible. Only `\pset format csv` and `pset format unaligned` seem possible.

Comment: Yes I tried many possibilities but not getting the needed format. Is there any way to achieve the format in psql.

Comment: It is not the purpose of an interactive client to do arbitrary formatting of the query results (`psql` is pretty good). Perhaps you should look for some specialized reporting software.